# Set the default entity for a lookup triggered from outlook with CRM Dynamics 2011

Tags: outlook, customization, dynamics-crm-2011, lookup

I'm trying to set the default lookup entity in the form triggered by a multi-entity "Set Regarding" lookup field.

The [javascript tweak](http://crmentropy.blogspot.com/2010/07/default-entity-for-multi-entity-lookups.html) set from the entity form is not enough for me, as most of the users work with the outlook integration of CRM. There is a "Set Regarding" option on any outlook email right click, which opens the CRM Lookup form.

[(See Outlook integration)](http://i45.tinypic.com/33wqh69.png)

I've done most of my customizations with javascript tweaks so far, but I can't find any "Lookup" form that I could directly work with. Is there any other way to customize these forms ?

Comment: On premise or online? Supported or unsupported? And should this apply to all set regarding windows, or just to those opened from the Outlook client, or just to those that show all entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's part of the Outlook Integration and isn't able to be customized via the Personal Options (or any other known way).  Additionally, there isn't any JavaScript to get at to customize from your inbox.

I hate to say it, but the only way I know of would be to write your own Outlook add-on to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is unsupported my Microsoft but..

Take a look at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb_controls\lookup\lookupinfo.aspx

In the Windows_OnLoad event put the following JS lines in.

document.getElementById("selObjects").value = "2"; // set default to 'Contact'
document.getElementById("selObjects").onchange();

You can find the value that you need in the dbo.EntityView.